# How to create Organization and space in mindsphere using cloudfoundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

When I am using the following code:

```
cf create-org (ORG_name)
```

I am getting an error:

> You are not authorized to perform the requested action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a Developer tenant, then you will already have an org for the tenant, which has the same name as the tenant. You can't create another org. By default, only the tenant owner is in the OrgManager role which can access the org.

Either:

1. Get the tenant owner to add you to the OrgManager role
2. Use MindSphere Settings to create Service Credentials for Cloud Foundry. This will allow you to login to cf using those credentials, access the cf org and add your real user to the org

Answer (score 0):

In many distributions of Cloud Foundry, an org represents an entire company or account so you likely won't be able to create another org without signing up for another account. ([See MindSphere documentation](https://developer.mindsphere.io/concepts/concept-cloudfoundry-apps.html#compute-resources))

Orgs and spaces are used to control user permissions and organize resources such as apps and services. Unless you are trying to create a space that you don't want your org manager to see, you might just [create a new space](https://developer.mindsphere.io/paas/howtos/howtos-space-management.html#create-a-new-space) instead.

Comment: Yes actually we need access... with normal mindsphere account we can't do.. we need developer account to push the application to mindsphere

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have used to push my application to mindsphere, but it was not done because i used normal user account. It need developer account to push the account.